# Media player libraries in Java

Tags: java, streaming, media-player

I am evaluating libraries for playing audio/video in Java. *It does not need to be 100% Java*; Java bindings to native libraries are perfectly OK. An external application that can be controlled from Java is also fine, as long as it can render video on a Java component.

The target platform is Linux. Windows support is a plus, but not required.

I have played with VLC using the [VLCj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) bindings, and it works pretty well in general, but keeps crashing occasionally when put under stress. I have also used mplayer in [slave mode](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt), which looks good. But I'd like to evaluate other options as well.

These are the requirements:

- Live playback of H.264, MPEG4 through RTP using RTSP. Extra points for MJPEG over HTTP.
- Able to render video on a Java (Swing or AWT) Component
- Open source, and actively maintained
- **Stable, rock-solid**

Suggestions? Advice?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I've spent the last month playing with several options and these are the results:

1. [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). This was my first thought, as everybody keeps saying that it "plays everything". I have used both the [VLCj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) Java bindings, and the built-in [remote interface](http://www.videolan.org/doc/play-howto/en/ch04.html#id501902) (`-I rc`). I found this to work pretty well in general, but had some issues. I kept seeing ocassional crashes under heavy load (not VLCj's fault as it also happens when using the binary directly). Also I've found memory consumption to be relatively high when compared to other options.
2. [MPlayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/). This actually performs better than VLC in my experience, no crashes, and memory consumption is lower. No Java bindings, although the [slave mode](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt) works very well.
3. [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/features/). Very powerful, very flexible, while still easy to get started with. Tried both the [Java bindings](http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/) and running the [`gst-launch`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/faq/html/chapter-using.html) binary from Java. Both approaches work remarkably well.
4. [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/) looked good, however it seems to have issues with RTP (as stated [in the FAQ](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Does_Xuggler_support_RTP)). Since both GStreamer and MPlayer worked so well, I did not get past the initial research.

I found GStreamer to be the best solution given the requirements, with MPlayer being the second option.

Comment: Xuggler is deprecated. It is replaced by HumbleVideo (https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video). HumbleVideo is **dormant** since the January the 3rd of 2015 (last commit) ...

Answer (score 3):

have you looked at [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/features/)?

Comment: I know of gstreamer, but I have no experience with it. Have you used it? Can you share your experience?

Answer (score 2):

I've also spent a while researching my options, and I've actually come to the conclusion that VLCJ is the best option - however here's the clincher, you need to run it out of process (especially with multiple players) for it to give you 100% reliable operation. That's the approach I'm taking and I've yet to see it crash. With it rock solid in this way it also has other advantages:

- It can play pretty much anything. Yes it's a bit of a cliche, but this includes DVDs, Youtube videos, pretty much any video file...
- Should support Linux / Mac / Windows, though I've yet to verify Mac working.
- Actively maintained, and if you ask a good (as in well thought out) question on the discussion group the owner often replies in minute in my experience!
- Open source, and the Google group activity at the time of writing is high.
- Uses all the graphics acceleration VLC does
- Able to play to any heavyweight Canvas component (and if you use the direct player, you get the BufferedImage to display anywhere you like, even in JOGL 3D land if you're that crazy!

I haven't found it that heavy on the resources front either, though I haven't done any thorough testing (but 3 players work fine in tandem as well as my relatively power-hungry application on my 4 year old basic laptop!)

Disadvantages? There's no official framework for out of process players, so you have to build one yourself (see [here](http://berry120.blogspot.com/2011/07/using-vlcj-for-video-reliably-with-out.html) for how I did it). And you do sometimes have to do some fiddling to get it working. But as far as I can see, it's working well for me so far!

Comment: Very interesting, especially the hint on running it out of process. I'll need to have another look at this. Still I would like to note that the crashes I was experiencing were also reproducible with the VLC binary. Thus not a VLCj-specific issue. Thanks for sharing your experience!

Comment: @Grodriguez I haven't been able to reproduce any crashes that way I must admit - have you considered filing a bug report for libvlc? And did these crashes occur with the new version 2 of libvlc (I've been using that without any problems even though it's in beta.) Of course the advantage with the out of process approach is that if it does bring down the VM, you can silently bring up a new one and just display an appropriate message in your application. I run all my players out of process (i.e. don't even have one in the main VM) for this reason.

Comment: I may need to go back and check VLCj again. Your feedback is inspiring (I also have to say that so far I'm very happy with GStreamer :)

Comment: I've tested VLCJ using libVLC (v.1.2.0) running 4 "direct" streaming videos simultaneously in the same process...so far so good

Comment: @ee the problem is while *most* of the time you'll probably be fine, sometimes you won't - and there's no guarantee as to when that will happen, apart from the likelihood is that it will every so often. If it's an app that means you can live with the occasional crash, fair enough, but if you want it to be rock solid then the in process approach won't ever cut it...

Comment: @berry120 thanks. in your case, are you intend to run your app for a longer time: like more than one day?

Comment: @ee. Well it's an app for projecting lyrics / videos / multimedia in church services - so while (I hope!) they wouldn't last for more than a day, it does need to be as reliable as I can make it since there's nothing worse than whatever software you're using crashing then having to hold the service up while you sort the problem out! It's not really the length of time that's the issue, more that it needs to be reliable in order to do its job properly.

Comment: I am stress-testing my 4-video streaming in-process app right now (all videos running): it is 18 hours since 6PM yesterday. So far so good..I can interact with it in the normal way. It doesn't look like it is going to fail soon. While it is running, I check its process stats..I notice the handle count keeps increasing (now at 5x,xxx) but I don't know which type of handle they are individually. Definitely, they are not file/disk I/O handles (zero activity); maybe network I/O handles. GDI+USER+thread handles remain constant. Physical mem usage (working set) stays at 2xx MB.

Comment: The increasing handle count comes from threads that involve JNA calls and libVLC calls to VLC core and VLC plugins made by each active video streaming session. These threads will eat quite a large amount of private bytes (virtual memory) over time.

Comment: Clarification: `These threads will eat quite a large amount of private bytes (virtual memory) over time` compared to working sets (physical memory)