# How to play video in javaFX on linux

Tags: java, linux, video, javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to make a multi-platform JAVAFX desktop app and I want it to play a video. Here is a sample code -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        MediaView mediaview = new MediaView();
        anchorPane.getChildren().addAll(mediaview);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Linux Video Play Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(anchorPane, 540, 210));
        primaryStage.show();

        File file=new File("video.flv");
        Media media=new Media(file.toURI().toString());
        MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaview.setMediaPlayer(mediaplayer);
        mediaplayer.play();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

'video.flv' is present in the same folder and the codec information can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BJb9.png)

The above code works perfectly on Windows (Win 10, x64, JDK 1.8.92), but gives the following error on Linux (Ubuntu 16.10, x64, JDK 1.8.112) -

```
Exception in Application start method
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:511)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:414)
    at Main.start(Main.java:24)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
    at com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:274)
    at com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:467)
    ... 11 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I make it work on Linux? 
I understand that there are some dependencies like 'glib', 'libavformat', etc. But when I tried

```
sudo apt-get install glib
```

it says

```
E: Unable to locate package glib
```

Same issue with libavformat53. Please note that video format restriction is not an issue, I'll be providing the video files to the users of my app. So if I can manage to make even one format work (say, flv), that will do, I can convert all the videos into that format. Also, I don't want my end users to go through any trouble to make it work, like typing commands on terminal etc. I intend to distribute the app as a ".deb" file, and I would like it to be so that the users can just download the deb file and click it and install it (via ubuntu software center,etc.) and it works (play video on linux). Once installed, launching the app will first fire a bash script which will then launch the main jar. I am considering two options -

1) - Specify all dependencies (glib, libavformat) in the deb package itself so they get installed with the app. But the problem is I'm on ubuntu 16.10 and the older libs (glib2.28 and libavformat53) are not available in repo. I can find glib2.50 and libavformat57 but they dont seem to work (or maybe I'm doing something wrong). So is there a way to specify the dependency and repo both in the deb file so they get installed easily? If not, I can maybe expect the user to give root access once, so I can install these libs via the bash script which fires when app starts, is that possible?

2) - I'm also considering ditching "javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer" completely and using some third party library like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3886056/media-player-libraries-in-java). But these solutions all seem very complicated so if anyone can help me by pointing in the right direction. Also most of these libraries seem to be under copyleft (GPL3/LGPL3) and i want to keep my app closed sourced. Is that possible?

Ps: This is my first ever post on Stackoverflow, so please pardon me if I've made any mistakes. Also, sorry for bad english. :)

Answer (score 1):

The Mediaplayer needs the library libavformat54 and all its needed libraries. I tried it with Debian 9(stretch) and got it. The needed libraries are mostly in Debian 7(wheezy), a few one are still in Debian 9. You must load down all the needed libraries which are not part of your distribution by hand and install it with dpkg. With libmp3lame0 I had the most problems because you need the pure library, but you will mostly find an repacked version.
libavformat54 needs libavcodec54 and libavutil51_1.0.10. When you have installed this two libraries you can install libavformat54. So beginn with the two libraries and look what they need and get the needed libraries from the internet. I think the best side is pkgs.org to get the needed libraries.